# Content not clearing after select and type on it in text box

Tags: html, angular

How can I automatically overwrite selected content?

I have a text box within a html table. there I have use following ng-pattern to get  2 decimal places.

```
ng-pattern="/^(?:(?=[1-9])([0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,7}){0,1})|(?=[0-0])(0+\.[0-9]{0,1}[1-9]([0-9]*)))$/"
```

When there is a value with two decimals in the textbox and I'm trying to select the value and type on it, the previous content does not get deleted.

Comment: Can you also add your html code and .ts file code

Comment: I've formatted your code and slightly rephrased your question.

Answer (score 0):

use `onfocus="this.value='';"`to always clear the field.

ex-:

`<input type="text" onfocus=" { this.value = ''; }" value="value" />`